# Get my own IP address

Tags: c, linux, networking

If I use `getHostByName()` I only get "127.0.0.1", because it is written on /etc/host, but this is not useful to me.

However, with the following java code I actually get what I want:

```
NetworkInterface.getByName(("eth0")).getInetAddresses().nextElement().getHostAddress()
```

I think that there is a way to get the same ip address also from C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`getifaddrs`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).

Answer (score 2):

That indicates the notorious Linux /etc/hosts misconfiguration problem. The hosts file should map 127.0.0.1 to localhost, and your real IP address to your real hostname.

Comment: But that's not useful for laptops since you may not have a permanent real IP address. Mapping the name to local loopback satisfies some tools that need to find it and works everywhere. So that's preferred for laptops Unless you like editing your /etc/hosts every time you move around.